# Markers on heatmap is not hiding (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have JS code to filter markers on map

Here is it

```
 $('#filter').on('click',
   function () {
       var startValue = $('#startDate').val();
       var endValue = $('#endDate').val();

       map.markers = [];
       map.markers.push(marker);
       //console.log(map.markers);
       $.each(map.markers, function (i, marker) {
           console.log(marker);
           if (marker.date === startValue)
               marker.setMap(null);


       });
   });
```

But markers not hiding.

Here is screen of console log

[image]

value of `startValue` is

[image]

As I understood it not hiding because of value in array and value from input is different?

How I can fix it?

**UPDATE**

After @scaisEdge answer I edited code like this

```
 $('#filter').on('click',
   function () {
       var startValue = $('#startDate').val();
       var endValue = $('#endDate').val();
       var myDate = new Date(startValue);
       map.markers = [];
       map.markers.push(marker);
       //console.log(map.markers);
       $.each(map.markers, function (i, marker) {
           console.log(marker);
           if (marker.date === myDate)
               marker.setMap(null);
       });

   });
```

But markers are still visible.

Here is fiddle of all script

jsfiddle.net/nemesises666/pj6wa52h/3

Comment: The date property of your markers seems to be a string and not a date object (nor a date string in the format `dd/MM/YYYY`). Besides, those dates in the console have an invalid timestamp. There is no date over timestamp `2147483648`

Comment: My bad. Database timestamps are in seconds. JS Date.now() is in miliseconds. Your Dates should be valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date instances (as in `new Date()`) are objects. Two objects are not equal unless they are the same object.

You could try:

```
       var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join(''); // "1508341846000"
       var markerDate = new Date( parseFloat( getDate ) );
       var valDate = new Date(startValue);
       if ( markerDate.getTime() === valDate.getTime() ) {
           marker.setMap(null);
       } else {
          console.log('marker date is',markerDate.getTime(),'valdate is',valDate.getTime());
       }
```

To compare number vs number

**EDIT**: added an else condition to check why dates time differs

**EDIT2**: I can see now that your markers are not `google.maps.Marker` instances but instead `google.maps.visualization.WeightedLocation` objects which don't have a "setMap" method. Heatmaps can update their data as a whole, not by turning off a particular datapoint.

You loop should be something like

```
var auxMarkers=[];

$.each(map.markers, function (i, datapoint) {
      if (datapoint should be kept in the heatmap) {
         auxMarkers.push(datapoint);
      }
});

Heatmap.setData(auxMarkers);
```

Comment: It's still not hiding.

Comment: But now it all in Date properties.

Comment: please create jsfiddle for all us to see it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nemesises666/pj6wa52h/3/

Here is Fiddle with js code of script file

I have error `Uncaught TypeError: marker.setMap is not a function`  in  this row 

`Heatmap.js:259 Uncaught TypeError: marker.setMap is not a function;`

And I don't understand, how to fix it

Comment: I created fiddle @KresimirPendic

Comment: added an edit with some seudocode.

Comment: Okay, but how I need to write condition in `if` to hide heatpoints ?

Comment: Filter values, after it clear map and populate it with new data?

Comment: Just use `setData` on Heatmap. It will ovewrite previous points.

Answer (score 0):

if your input is if format 09/11/2017

try build a proper data as

```
 var myDate  =   new Date(startValue);
```

Comment: It not helps. I updated post

Comment: check for the real contengt of both the value you compare and convert properly ...

Comment: For marker.date in console is `undefined`.

For myDate is `Mon Sep 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)`

Comment: if you have undefined  date  then you can't compare  with a valid date ...  check why you have undefined  date in your marker and not the value  you showed  in your img .. check for real content and format  of your JSON

Comment: I have this in my JSON when set breakpoint on back-end

`CurrentDateTime {10/18/2017 6:50:46 PM} System.DateTime`

Comment: So it looks like valid.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this..

I first strip value from marker.date to float and into Date, then compare it with selected date,, see if that works for you

```js
$('#filter').on('click',
   function () {
       var startValue = $('#startDate').val();
       var endValue = $('#endDate').val();

       map.markers = [];
       map.markers.push(marker);
       //console.log(map.markers);
       $.each(map.markers, function (i, marker) {
           var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join(''); // "1508341846000"
           var markerDate = new Date( parseFloat( getDate ) );
           var valDate = new Date(startValue);
           if ( markerDate === valDate )
               marker.setMap(null);

       });
   });
```

Comment: I have this `ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

Comment: But I don't understood why undefined. I see it value in `console.log`

Comment: can you put output from console for markers so I can test here or on jsfiddle?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Zm3vPC8g

Comment: that should work right,, sorry to ask but is this page available for you to share so I can test on that page or it's localy somewhere?

Comment: It's locally on my pc.

Comment: I will create fiddle and update post

Comment: I created fiddle